# Counting the total number duplicate specific values in 2 columns

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-2007

I am using Office 2007 and have this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(K5:K254,ROW(K5:K254)-ROW(K5),0,1)),--(K5:K254="24""")) + SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(O5:O254,ROW(O5:O254)-ROW(N5),0,1)),--(O5:O254="24"""))
```

and appropriate one for each of the 17", 19", 22" and 23" monitor special row boxes that I need to have an accurate count of.

My problem is that for some reason the above formula will only count from K:K the number of monitors but will not do the same on N:N

I tried

```
=COUNTIF(K:K,"24""")+COUNTIF(N:N,"24""")-COUNTIFS(N:N,"24""",O:O,"Personal")
```

but it will get me the *circular reference warning error* even if at first I do get correct number of monitors, but after the error flashes the value is 0.

My goal is to have a formula that can count from 2 separate columns (K and N) the exact number of company monitors minus the personal ones when I apply a filter in F-S monitors.
My data has 254 names of users with other details and for the monitor evidence data is listed as below:

```
K column has Monitor1: 17", 19", 22", 23" and 24"
L column has HP, Lenovo, F-S, n/a
N column has Monitor2: 17", 19", 22", 23" and 24"
O column has HP, Lenovo, F-S, n/a, Personal
```

Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: please make this readable

Comment: Text has been updated with some text formatting help from someone with more experience on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same formula adjusted to apply to N rather than K:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(N5:N254,ROW(N5:N254)-ROW(N5),0,1)),--(N5:N254="24""")) + SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(R5:R254,ROW(R5:R254)-ROW(Q5),0,1)),--(R5:R254="24"""))
```

Simply adding the two together might be what you want.